# Uncaught ReferenceError: calcAge is not defined

Tags: javascript, object

I have created a simple object below,

```js
let user = {
  birthYear: 1991,
  calcAge: function () {
     return 2021 - this.birthYear; 
},
 currentAge: calcAge(), //`-------------------- x`
};

console.log(user.calcAge());
```

getting an error at `x` with reference error. What can be the error?

Answer (score 2):

The function is defined inside the `user` object. Therefore you call it via `user.calcAge()` like so:

```js
let user = {
  birthYear: 1991,
  calcAge: function() {
    return 2021 - this.birthYear;
  },
  currentAge: function() {
    return user.calcAge();
  },
};

console.log(user.currentAge());
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple different ways to get this working.

Could simplify and turn `calcAge` into a function inherently:

```
let user = {
  birthYear: 1991,
  calcAge () {
    return 2021 - this.birthYear;
  },
};

console.log(user.calcAge());
```

Maybe breaking out your variables to being more explicit:

```
let user = {
  birthYear: 1991,
  currentYear: 2021,
  
  calcAge () {
    return this.currentYear - this.birthYear;
  },
};

console.log(user.calcAge());
```

Could consider [using an Object getter.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) This treats it as a property of an object as opposed to an invoked method.

```
let user = {
  birthYear: 1991,
  currentYear: 2021,

  get currentAge() {
    return this.currentYear - this.birthYear;
  },
};

console.log(user.currentAge);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another way you can go about it.

```js
let user = {
  birthYear: 1991,
  calcAge: function() {
    this.currentAge = 2021 - this.birthYear;
  }
}
user.calcAge()
console.log(user.currentAge);
```